# EditText hardcoded string used as integer value

Tags: android, integer

I have a `EditText` in my xml file. But i use a default value "1" as the text for the `EditText`. I know why I shouldn't hardcode strings but it is a integer value that always has "1" as default. so should I still enter the value in a string or should I ignore themessage?

Comment: If you target a recent enough API then you could swap the EditText with a NumberPicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me, it's ok to ignore the warning in your scenario. Anyway, if you want to get rid of it, you could declare an *integer* instead of a *string* (in a resource file `integers.xml` for instance), like.-

```
<integer name="integer1">1</integer>
```

And set it in your `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@integer/integer1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should enter the value "1" in strings.xml that is good practice because suppose later you want to make default as "0" or "2" anything different then that will be easy just go in strings.xml and make the change.